# Infinite finitely generated groups whose Frattini factors are Klein 4-group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there an infinite finitely generated group whose Frattini factor is isomorphic to Klein 4-group?

Comment: By Frattini factor, do you mean its Frattini subgroup or the quotient by the Frattini subgroup?  Or something else?

Comment: @HJRW. I mean the quotient by the Frattini subgroup.

Comment: I think an equivalent form of the question is whether there can be an infinite group $G$ which has exactly three maximal subgroups each of index $2$ ( if there is such a $G$, it must be generated by two elements).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson. Actually it is equivalent to ask if there is an infinite finitely generated group with exactly 3 maximal subgroups (without any other restriction on the indices).

Comment: @AndreiJaikin. Andrei Jaikin-Zapirain has sent an answer in Group-Pub-forum at  2016/Aug/21 as follows:                                                                                                  An example of an infinite group with 3 maximal subgroups can be extracted from the paper

Ershov, Mikhail; Jaikin-Zapirain, Andrei Groups of positive weighted deficiency and their applications. J. Reine Angew. Math. 677 (2013), 71–134.

A 2-generated 2-LERF group (see Section 7 of  the paper) has this property because its maximal subgroups have index 2.

Comment: @AndreiJaikin I wish he can put his answer himself here! This answers (Problem 17.17 of THE KOUROVKA NOTEBOOK, No. 18; https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0300v8.pdf) proposed by G.M.Bergman:

 If a finitely generated group $G$ has $n < \infty$ maximal subgroups, must $G$ be finite? In particular, what if $n = 3$?